# output with single quote in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle10g

Table Values

### CNAME

Firstname
Amount
Postalcode
Lastname
Accountnumber

### REQUIRED O/P

### CNAME

'Firstname'
'Amount'
'Postalcode'
'Lastname'
'Accountnumber'

Comment: Where is the problem? more details can help

Comment: Here you find  something on [ask] and how to build a [mcve] that can be useful to improve your question.Among the others, Oracle or Mysql?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 2):

In `mysql` you can use the function [`concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
SELECT CONCAT("'", CNAME, "'") FROM yourTable
```

In `oracle` you can use the same function as above [`concat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm) or the [`concatenation operator`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm):

```
SELECT '''' || CNAME || '''' FROM yourTable;
SELECT CONCAT('''', CNAME, '''') FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: In Oracle, you use single quotes to enclose strings not double quotes (and a single quote inside a string needs to be escaped by using two single quotes), so it should actually be: `select ''''||cname||'''' from yourtable;` or, using the quoted string function, `select q'{'}'||cname||q'{'}' from yourtable;`

Comment: `||` is also ANSI SQL concatenation. However, use single quotes for string literals, and if you want a single quote in a string literal, escape it with another single quote (e.g. `'''' || cname || '''' ...`.)