# How to append single quote in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need some help to find out some solution in mysql.

Here is my string,

> IT,Business,IT & Software Development, IT Services, ERP
>   Solution,Industrial Supply,IT & Software Development

and I want this type of output using mysql query.

> 'IT','Business','IT & Software Development', 'IT Services', 'ERP
>   Solution','Industrial Supply','IT & Software Development'

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything? The MySQL string functions [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and [`REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) can be used to do the job.

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736930/output-with-single-quote-in-sql) you can simply use the concat operator.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT("'",
            REPLACE("IT,Business,IT & Software Development, IT Services, ERP Solution,Industrial Supply,IT & Software Development",",","','"),
        "'");
```

SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/19140